# Multipart CSV Upload Node

Tags: node.js, api, qualtrics

Hello i'm trying to turn 2 arrays into 2 rows of data but the issue is that I can't seem to send it correctly using fetch

This is what i currently have, but one issue is that my Readable isn't a text/csv, it's an octet/application

Any help would be fantastic
[image]

status: 413,
  statusText: 'Request Entity Too Large',

Here is the URL to the API route i'm attempting to hit, the createFileString should be a CSV styled string with \n denoted for rows, and the first row is the "header"

edit:
The error code suggests that the size is to large, but my question is simply how can i turn this readable into a CSV in my FormData Thanks.

Comment: What i'm looking for is how to turn a string into a CSV and send it using fetch or request., @theremix didn't answer my question

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
status: 413, statusText: 'Request Entity Too Large'
```

Is an error from the server. So the http server, or reverse proxy, would have a configurable request body size limit. If you are in control of the server, you can increase the server max client body size.

Comment: I understand the issue, but I'm also sending an Octet/application, I'm trying to figure out how to create a readable and send it as a text/csv